# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT | ArrayList issue

Tags: android, gson

I'm using the Gson library to save and retrieve an ArrayList of Players Objects.

---

### My onStop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String guardJSON = gson.toJson(playersNoGuard);
    editor.putString(GUARD, guardJSON);

    editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
    editor.apply();
}
```

### My onCreate important part

```
ArrayList<Player> playersNoGuard;
RecyclerView myList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_players_guard);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String guardJSON = prefs.getString(GUARD, null);
    Type arrayListPlayers = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Player>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    if(guardJSON != null) {
        playersNoGuard = gson.fromJson(guardJSON, arrayListPlayers);
    }

    // Get the players and remove the Clairvoyant
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    playersNoGuard = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("PLAYERS");

    [...] // Code skipped

    }
```

---

But when this Activity is run, I get the following error log:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

What's wrong in this code?

Comment: your json is an object not an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654042/gson-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object)

Comment: I' not sure that's my specific case

Comment: Why not?! @TimCastelijns

Comment: How am I supposed to know that.. it's your data not mine

Comment: I've sjown you the code, how I save and retrieve it. Thus I've also used the same code in other Activities and I get no errors, what ya think? @TimCastelijns

Comment: It doesn't matter what I "think", your json is an object not an array - it's a fact not a thought

Comment: Yeah and how's this supposed to help me solve the issue @TimCastelijns

Comment: You probably write to the same preferences entry somewhere else. Ensure that your key is unique.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was missing. Please @F43nd1r may you post an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably write to the same preferences entry somewhere else. Ensure that your key (`GUARD`) is unique throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Response while Gson converting a response it expected Array in response but in your response you have made you are passing Object.

This is already answered [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654042/gson-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object) and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210000/retrofit-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array?rq=1)**

[**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array) is reverse situation described.

Comment: Why am I passing an Object? I saved it as an ArrayList, I've used this same code for other ArrayLists and I get no errors

Comment: *This is already answered here and here* why dont you flag for duplicate instead of posting an answer then

Comment: Guys, all these examples are not helping in my case, or at least I don't see how. I've used this code in other Activities and it's working fine. what did I do wrong?